# GET request fails on server

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send a GET request with proxy.

It **works** as expected in my local environment (windows):

```py
# Get proxies
proxies_list = ['204.1xx.xxx.xx:999', '85.1x.xxx.xx:3128'...]
# Set headers
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

# Go over all the proxy addresses and try to get response, if successful, stop execution
for proxy in proxies_list:
    try:
        print(f'trying {proxy}...')
        proxies = {'http': proxy, 'https': proxy}
        response = requests.get(url='https://httpbin.org/ip', headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
        print(response.status_code)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print('success')
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

However, when running the very same code, from my development server (Ubuntu droplet in Digital Ocean) I'm getting a timeout error for all requests, or, if I send the requests without a timeout argument, I simply never get a response.

This is unexpected behavior since the same request with the same proxy address works from my local machine.
Any ideas on how to solve/ debug this any further?

Comment: Is your local machine on a private/corporate VPN? If so, is your Ubuntu droplet peered with that VPN? It sounds like the network topology is different, and the droplet just can't see your proxies

Comment: @C.Nivs No, I'm using proxies from https://free-proxy-list.net/